Help identify a 1980s vertical space shooter
I need help identify a 1980s vertical space shooter. It was a coin operated arcade game, I remember it around the mid 80's at a local aracde. The player's spacecraft was at the bottom, and fired up at colorful polygons which remind me of asteroids. The polygons moved downward toward the player's craft. When shot they would split in half. The halves when shot would spit in half one more time. The polygon asteroid things kind of reminded me of jello cubes. There was no boss level that I remember. The enemies moved left and right and down at random agles. It was wave after wave, or sheet after sheet of enemies. No boss level that I ever got to.

How did the "enemies"/polygons fly or move? Was there a boss level, or boss - or was it just new sheet after sheet of enemies? As it stands the question is lacking details and seems a little bit vague. Please [edit] and update with any more info that might help the identification.

Did the polygons approach the player one at a time (one per screen), or in a staggered fashion (one or two per screen), or as a sheet (like space invaders)?

Are you sure you are not half-confusing it with asteroids? Polygons splitting in half when shot is more or less the defining trait of asteroids, and if you only remember the ship sitting at the bottom, it would fit exactly your description. Some arcade games had colored bands over the screen to turn black&white graphics into color, so if for some reason a run-of-the-mill asteroids game ended up with this screen, then you'd have your colorful polygons.

Adding more information is especially helpful for odd games. This may include things like what country / region / city was the arcade located, what arcade brand. Likewise more about the machine, like cabinet type, brand and so on.

There's enough information here to make a good guess at the game: Challenger https://www.igdb.com/games/challenger https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v79vZzEOgHE

Sounds like Missle Command! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile_Command A lot of fun back in the day. :D
